# On Windows/NTFS can a symbolic link be moved to another computer?

Tags: windows, iis, symlink, junction

For the purposes of a security test involving Windows servers, I would like to attempt uploading a Symbolic link to a Windows web application. However, based on the information officially available, it is unclear whether Windows hard links (Which I suppose are the same as NTFS junctions) exist as a file that can be copied from the hard disk the same way it does on Linux. It's vague, but I get the sense that NTFS junctions are some other kind of file system artifacts which is different than "regular" files - I can't find the documentation to confirm or deny this. I.E NTFS I want to know if NTFS supports the direct manipulation of the symlink record such that I could move the symlink to a different computer.

I am aware that Windows softlink files (.lnk) are not limited in this way, but they do not suit the purposes of the test.

My Aim is to copy a symlink off of a virtual machine, and then upload it to the server which I am testing.

Is this possible? (I am under the impression it is not.) From what I have seen absolutely every program on Windows would regard the hardlink as the destination file. Is there a way around this, perhaps by using a special editor to temporarily corrupt the file? If the symlink exists as a normal file on the file system can the symlink be altered so it can moved to a non-Windows OS for further use?

Let me know if this would be a better question for server fault. Since this is not directly about security, and is more of mundane technical problem in the service of a security exercise, I don't think it would fit on Stack Exchange security.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to provide a very direct answer. I work on a backup/repair/imaging project, and I copy whole disk images to a server via a web service - so, it's possible to do what you want, but there's a lot to consider.

Hardlinks

It is generally assumed that hardlinks cannot be distinguished from each other, however, there is a subtle difference between linked files and their "original" file. That difference is that queries to the `$MFT` (using USN-related arguments on the winapi function `DeviceIOControl`) will only return one of the files. This may be considered the *original* file. You can then call the winapi function `NtQueryInformationFile` to enumerate the hard links.

Symlinks and junctions are different animals...

You can know that a *folder* is a junction or a symlink, by getting the attributes from it. There's a ReparsePoint flag in the attributes if it's a junction or a symlink. BTW - the difference between junctions and symlinks is that the junction is a redirect to another location on the same volume, while a symlink is a redirect to an off-volume location. The redirect target is always another folder either way.

What's interesting is that both symlinks and junctions look and act like folders, while they are *really* files containing redirect information. When you open 'em, NTFS will normally look at the redirect, and open the redirect target. NTFS checks the permissions at the redirect target, so as an attack, this might not be a robust strategy.

When opening a junction/symlink, you can add a flag `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT`. When you do this, NTFS does not perform the redirect, but opens the *content*, which is actually redirect information, and assuming you know the format of that information, it is possible to reconstruct the junction/symlink at the server. Note that the redirect may point to a location that may not exist, or may exist only temporarily. This is expected as some network resources may not always be available.

So, in short, it's possible to copy a junction or a symlink...while copying a hard link nominally means copying the file...with the foregoing subtleties in mind. You can create a hard link manually, too, as long as the target file exists.

With hardlinks, there's one interesting kink in the NTFS security picture. If a user has access to a file, and you create a hardlink to that file in a folder the user doesn't have access to, the user can still open that file using the path to the hard link. This is because the link and the original file are both pointing to the same file (and security info) on disk. Permissions changed on any of the links affect all the links. Without knowing this, you can inadvertently wreak havoc on a file system :-)

I know this is a bit helter-skelter, so let me summarize this way:

NTFS directory entries can be folders or files. Hardlinks are directory entries that all point to one file. Symlinks and junctions are really files that *act like* folders for most practical purposes (until you know how to get at the redirect info as described above).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR, NTFS (directory) junctions are actually symbolic links. The juctnion is implemented as a special file attribute called repars point that contains the link target.

Hardlinks, on the other hand, are implemented as direct references to the base MFT record of the target file and are stored as regular entries inside directory tree. You actually cannot distinguish a hardlink from the "original" file (every file and directory actually has at least one hardlink since it is contained somewhere within the directory tree).

If you wish to copy a symbolic link itself, you need to know that it is a symbolic link and extract the information about its target. File operations (except deletion and, probably, renamng) are redirected to the link target. So, you can, in general, copy a symbolic link by creating its exact copy in the destination area.

The actual question is, whether the interface you are using to perform the copy operation allows you to create symbolic links on the target.

Comment: I am trying to accomplish this by uploading to link directly to a webserver via an application. The goal is to trick IIS into following the link so that I could grab files which are not authorized for my user. Replacing files with symlinks is a common attack on Unix systems.

Comment: @baordog did you ever test if this was possible? what did you find?

Comment: As I recall, it is not possible, but this was a long time ago so I could be wrong.